# What length should be used for openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()?

Tags: php, cookies, openssl

I need to generate a value that will go in a cookie so that I can uniquely identify users and after lots of reading it seems that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` might fit the bill.

However, I'm uncertain of what `length` parameter I should use for the function in order for the value to be unique. I.e: should I use a length of 10, 25, 50, 100, etc?

Comment: Why not the highest possible? Theoretically, it has the lowest chance of collisions (i.e. for two random values to be the same). This said, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(PHP_INT_MAX) seems to be the best.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello - wouldn't that result in an **incredibly** large cookie size?

Comment: Uhmm... on my system, PHP_INT_MAX gives 2147483647, which - multiplied by 1 byte - is about 2,147 GB.   
   
Almost fell from my chair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable (strong cryptographic) [security level](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Security_Level) today is 128 bits.  That is the same level of security that you'd get from symmetrical encryption using a 128 bit cipher (e.g. AES-128).  Assuming collisions would be a problem for your application because you want the values to be unique, we need to consider the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), and therefore you'd want 256 bits of random data in your cookie value.  That's 32 bytes for `length`.  Mounting a [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) at 256 bits takes around 2<sup>256/2</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> attempts to find a collision, which is equivalent to the 128 bit security level.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better function for your needs: `uniqid()`, which generates a (for what it's possible) random value, basend on `microtime()`. Of course, this is not cryptographically secure, but you didn't specify it had to be.

Usage: `uniqid()` returns a 13-characters-long string, `uniqid("", TRUE)` 23 characters, `uniqid($var)` yields `strlen($var)+13` characters.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation of uniqid:

### Caution

This function does not generate cryptographically secure tokens, in fact without being passed any additional parameters the return value is little different from microtime(). If you need to generate cryptographically secure tokens use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes().

Comment: Is this intended to be a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418252/3964927)?